# How can you short a bond if you think it's going to default when it comes due?

Tags: bonds, shorting-securities

For the first 29 years, a 30-year bond works more or less like any other security, and you can short it just like anything else. However, I'm interested in what happens if you want to short it at the 30-year mark exactly. You can't agree in advance to sell the bond at 30 years plus one week, because at that time the bond will no longer exist.

Let's say my prediction is that the market will trust a 30-year bond completely, right up until the final payment at which time the company will go bankrupt and fail to pay. Is there anything I can do to profit from this?

Comment: You know the risk profile changes over the course of the bond?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The company won't be instantly liquidated if it goes into bankruptcy. And if it does, then the bonds will not be repaid and therefore they will exist during the bankruptcy until final liquidation.

For the non-liquidation scenario (i.e. your assumption was wrong and it's paid at par) you can just settle the short at face value, since the bond has proven to be worth its face value.

Answer (score 0):

Going out on a limb here, but if you posit that the market trusts the 30-year bond completely up to and including the penultimate payment, why pay borrowing costs for the short position all that time?

Just let it be, then short it at the penultimate payment. Or if you have the capital and are happy with the income stream and the liquidity of the bond up to the penultimate payment, then buy it now and sell it at the penultimate payment.

If you're concerned about not being able to buy the bond back, consider the following (it refers to stocks, but it sounds like it would apply to bonds as well):

> Quite simply, if you have an open short position in a company that gets delisted and declares bankruptcy, then you don't have to pay back anyone because the shares are worthless.
>   - [investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/maintain-short-position-delisted-stock/)

---

*Disclaimer: this is not to be construed as financial advice.*

Comment: Buying and then selling the bond won't work. When you buy the bond, you are paying full value for the penultimate payment that you think is worthless. Nothing you can do after that makes up for that loss.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Buy/sell refers to extracting the coupon payments in the usual way over the first 29 years, not to get capital appreciation over the last year. The alternative strategy suggested for the last year (if they haven’t already bought the bond) is to short-sell the bond.

Comment: Since it requires him to overpay for the bond to get those payments, it's a losing strategy if he believes that the last payment will be defaulted on. Nothing that happens later in that strategy can make up for the initial overpayment -- it gets him absolutely nothing but something he overpaid for.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The OP has posits a market that trusts the bond completely. So the price should be near par just before the sale. Buy at par and sell near par - what overpayment are you talking about?

Comment: If he believes the last payment won't be made, then when he buys the bond, he is paying full price for the right to a payment he won't get. He'd have to be an idiot to do that. There's nothing he can do later to compensate him for that loss. Selling the bond before it defaults leaves him with no benefit because it, at best, cancels out some of the loss he took when he bought.

Comment: @David 29 years of coupon payments aren’t ‘nothing’. My answer has 2 value-extraction alternatives. ‘Buy and hold to nearly the end’ gives almost the same value as ‘buy and hold to the end’ would, had the bond been fully repaid on maturity. It gives max yield for a traditional bond strategy where he somehow determines that the bond will be reliable except right at the end (and where the market believes the bond will be reliable to the end). It’s not a leveraged gain, but it is certainly not a guaranteed loss. Perhaps you are objecting to something my answer didn’t propose.

Comment: Paying full price for a payment that you expect will not be made is a guaranteed loss if you're right. You say it "gives max yield for a traditional bond strategy", but that misses the entire point. His objective was not to get normal yield but to exploit the fact that he believes the last payment won't be made. Your strategy just makes absolutely no sense given the OP's assumptions. It starts with a huge loss and never does anything to get any kind of compensating gain to offset that starting loss. If the market gets wind of what he knows any time during the life of the bond, he's screwed.

Comment: @David You’ve missed my point and the OP’s assumption. I’m leaving this discussion here.

Answer (score 0):

Short the stock while holding the bond. If the company is in trouble then the gain on the short stock will be larger than the loss on the long bond. Also, if the company goes bankrupt then the holders of the senior debt mostly become the new stockholders with the previous stockholders usually wiped-out.